# WordPress Metabox with paypal form or can I add a link instead?

Tags: forms, wordpress, paypal

I have create a meta box in my WordPress posts, and I like to add a PayPal button/form.

The problem is that, because all the editing page in WordPress is wrapped by a form, even the meta boxes, is not posible to add the PayPal button form.

Is there any idea/approach to solve that issue?

Is ther a way to implement the paypal button like a link instead of form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme pass a variable from your admin meta box's and populate the form.

If you don't have those values per post, don't show the form.